# Regexp to match but don't capture middle part

Tags: sublimetext2, pcre

Im trying to create my own theme in Sublime Text 2 to highlight CSS syntax. All I have left is `keyframes`.

```
@-webkit-keyframes spin { /* some rules */ }

@-moz-keyframes colorize { /* some rules */ }

@-ms-keyframes spin { /* some rules */ }

@-o-keyframes spin { /* some rules */ }

@keyframes colorize { /* some rules */ }
```

I want to highlight the initial `@` and the word `keyframes` without highlighting engines prefixes, like `-webkit-`, or `-moz-`, so only `@keyframes` must be returned.

What is the right regexp for that?


I tried:

```
((?<=-webkit-)|(?<=-moz-)|(?<=-ms-)|(?<=-o-)|)keyframes
```

but that doesn't include the `@` and doesn't even return the `keyframes` in Sublime text at all.

**Update** ----

Thanks to [Cheruvian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1443896/cheruvian), I realized what was in front of me all along.

Sublime's parser structure is (I added the comments after I realized what are the `<key>name</key>`):

```
<dict>
    <!-- Regexp pattern -->
    <key>match</key>
    <string>\s*(@)(-(webkit|moz|ms|o)-)?(keyframes)</string>

    <!-- Referencing to the groups captured above -->
    <key>captures</key>
    <dict>

        <!-- 1st group captured -->
        <key>1</key>
        <dict>

            <!-- Referencing name -->
            <key>name</key>
            <string>keyword.control.keyframes.css</string>
        </dict>

        <!-- 2nd group captured -->
        <key>2</key>
        <dict>

            <!-- Referencing name -->
            <key>name</key>
            <string>punctuation.definition.keyword.css</string>
        </dict>

        <!-- n group captured -->
        <key>n</key>
        <dict>

            <!-- Referencing name -->
            <key>name</key>
            <string>some.name.css</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

From that, all I had to do was to group the regex and select the groups I wanted and give them some unique referencing strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming sublime uses capturing groups you can use:

```
(@).*?(keyframes)
```

regex capturing groups are indicated by parentheses. 
(From phone will try to clean up later)

Comment: I initially thought of the same thing, but dropped the idea as I wouldn't know how to reference to the groups captured. But now you got me digging (again) in Sublime's XML parser, managing to understand of how to do this. Thanks!